# How can I access a shell on the VM Linux host when using the Docker Windows Beta

Tags: docker

I have set up Docker for Windows (Hyperv Beta) on my Laptop.
My intention is to laborate on some setups for containers I intend to install in my real server later. I am fairly new to Docker (but know the basics) so I wanted to laborate with volumes and volume images a bit.

However all anonymous volumes end up on the virtual Linux host. I would like to access the filesystem of the host, not within a container.

I cannot access it from within a container easily due to (well founded) security constraints. Neither can I find a way to access it from the windows prompt.

(Using Docker for Windows version 1.12.0-beta21)

I know that it possible to mount volumes using the c share made by Docker for Windows, but that raises the complexity for me. My intent is to use Docker tutorials unmodified and inspect the results in the host filesystem. Preferably through a (bash) shell in the host VM or with a windows file access into the virtual machine.

Later on I would also like to copy volume contents into the vm volumes although that could be solved using a volume against the c drive.

Comment: On Mac you can connect via a shell command to the UNIX socket, not sure about Windows. Since the Mac / Windows apps are environment specific, you might be better off using a VM for a host, as your solution is going to be more portable.

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I am looking for. But for Windows.

Comment: I tried to attach to the HyperVisor screen. But it was just black and showed no signs of responding to the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have after research on my own deducted the following technique to create a privileged container that works as if it was the Linux root host. This is the best I have been able to pinpoint so far.

```
docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker-machine will allow you to ssh to the default machine by typing:

```
"docker-machine ssh"
```

You'll be logged into the VM that is running docker.